# Are feasible facilities for production of hydrogen and oxygen from water using only solar energy?

Tags: energy, water, sun

Are feasible facilities for production of hydrogen and oxygen from water using only solar energy? Should using Hydrogen as a source of energy be uncomparably more enviroment friendly than using oil?

Comment: Is free hydrogen as available as oil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question: Industrial production of hydrogen is currently  produced “in large quantities at reasonable costs,” according to an NRC report (https://www.nap.edu/read/10922/chapter/2). The problem with this generation is costly distribution. The report says that says that producing hydrogen by electricity from renewable sources (except possibly wind) for local end use is inefficient. They prefer direct production via “photobiological, photochemical, and thin-film solar processes.”

Second question: the report also concludes that, given a set of assumptions regarding feasibility of large scale production of generation, storage and vehicles that are of good performance, that yes the hydrogen economy would be highly beneficial both on environmental sustainability and economic  metrics and sociopolitical ones.

A large scale collaboration of academia, private sector and government agencies could solve this problem. But political (and nefarious) interference from the radical corporate right would make the effort impossible, IMO.